# select date time pairs where time difference is within 1 minute

Tags: c#-4.0, excel-formula

I am using excel with C#.
I have two date time lists in excel.
Goal is to select date time pairs from both list where the time difference is less than or equal to 1 minute.

[image]

From above image, T1 will come with those values from Time List2 where difference between T1 and any (TA or TB or TC etc) is within 1 min.

Let us say, difference between T1 and (TC and TA) qualifies. So pairs will be: T1/TC and T1/TA

Since both lists are quite long, I am trying to avoid 'for' loop.

Any easy way to get here?

Many thanks!!

P.S - can this be achieved in some other language? I am familiar with python and oracle and will try to understand if solution in any other language is possible.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a for loop?  In the C# space, what else are you going to use?

Comment: Only reason is it will take time. I am hoping if there is anything outside my knowledge that works.

Comment: Seems a straightforward solution in SQL. Create a cross join query, takenthe difference between the times and filter with a WHERE clause. No looping.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample for difference for 'many-to many' times?